# How to extract the a column with apply of filter

Tags: pandas

Data frame is below

```
import pandas as pd
import io
s = '''uid,col1,flag
1001,rejected,Audi
1002,verified,Benz
1003,verified,Ferrari
1004,rejected,Tesla'''
df_j = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))
```

Need to extract the row which `verified` 
Expected out is below

```
1002
1003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and selecting by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
s = df_j.loc[df_j['col1'] == 'verified', 'uid']
print (s)
1    1002
2    1003
Name: uid, dtype: int64
```